# Exploring ML files in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, jedit

I was wondering if in Isabelle ML files there is a way to activate the feature that normal theory files have, i.e, you can press Ctrl+click with mouse in a definition and get the desired definition.

However, this does not seem to work for ML files. Is there any option I can activate to navigate from a function to its definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to enable the feature that you seek would be to include the ML file in a `*.thy` file with the command `ML_file` and have both of them open in jEdit. Of course, there may exist better alternatives.