# How to find functionality of functions in Isabelle

Tags: verification, isabelle, formal-verification, formal-methods

I am trying to read the code of [HOL-Hoare](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL-Hoare/index.html) and I have trouble understanding the functionalities of many functions in hoare_tac.ML and hoare_syntax.ML. For instance, in

```
fun mk_abstupleC [] body = absfree ("x", HOLogic.unitT) body
  | mk_abstupleC [v] body = absfree (dest_Free v) body
  | mk_abstupleC (v :: w) body =
      let
        val (x, T) = dest_Free v;
        val z = mk_abstupleC w body;
        val T2 =
          (case z of
            Abs (_, T, _) => T
          | Const (_, Type (_, [_, Type (_, [T, _])])) $ _ => T);
      in
        Const (\<^const_name>‹case_prod›,
            (T --> T2 --> HOLogic.boolT) --> HOLogic.mk_prodT (T, T2) --> HOLogic.boolT) $
          absfree (x, T) z
      end;
```

I can't understand the functionality of **absfree** and **dest_Free** and I have to make some tests to get their meanings.
I have found some functionality description in [The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf) and [implementation](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021/doc/implementation.pdf), but not all functions are found.
So My question is **how to search functions conveniently**?

Comment: Does the following Q&A answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59091016/exploring-ml-files-in-isabelle/?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Press Ctrl+click with the mouse in a definition and get the desired definition.

Comment: Sorry, the last comment was automatically generated when I marked the question as duplicate. Please ignore it.

Comment: That's all right.